# Individual bit access in C

Tags: c, bitset

Im not that good at C, so go easy on me, but I wanted to be able to have individual bit access in C without using a ton of functions to do bit manipulation on a `uint8_t`.  Tell me where I could improve upon it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(1)
union bit_array {
    struct {
        unsigned char b8:1, b7:1, b6:1, b5:1, b4:1, b3:1, b2:1, b1:1;
    } bits;
    unsigned char value;
};

int main() {
    // Creates char with binary value 11111111
    union bit_array test = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    // Displays 11111111 (255)
    printf("%u\n", test.value);

    // Sets 8th bit of binary value to 0
    // 11111111 (255) -> 11111110 (254)
    test.bits.b8 = 0;

    // Displays 11111110 (254)
    printf("%u\n", test.value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your current code does not show how you intend to use the bitwise access. The `main` function should demonstrate exactly that, but in the code you posted, it doesn't. Without this information, we cannot tell you how to write _really_ good code for this task.

Comment: @RolandIllig The reason why i like this implementation is because you can do a lot of things with it, but I have now updated my code to show one of them.

Comment: b0 - b7 probably are more understandable. `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}` giving `hgfedcba` (if I read your code right) is also less evident. You set b8 but the bit to the right is set. At least if  11111110 means 254. **4.** `uint8_t` is better than `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4):

This code is not portable.  The order of bit-fields within a word is completely compiler-dependent, so the test that appears to work on one platform may give completely different results on another.

You have avoided a common trap of using signed 1-bit fields (which can hold values `0` and `-1`) - these unsigned ones are much better.

I don't think there's any need for the `bits` member to be named - I would use an anonymous member there.

The numbering of bits is unconventional - most programmers would expect `b0` to be the least-significant bit, and `b7` the most significant (corresponding to 2⁰ and 2⁷ value of those bits in integers).

The test would be better if it were *self-checking* - return with non-zero status if any of the expectations are not met.  For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int failures = 0;

    {
        /* First test */
        union bit_array test = { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} };
        if (test.value != 0xFF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Test 1 expected 0xff, got %#04hhx\n", test.value);
            ++failures;
        }
    }

    {
        /* Second test */
        union bit_array test = { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} };
        test.bits.b8 = 0;
        if (test.value != 0xFE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Test 2 expected 0xfe, got %#04hhx\n", test.value);
            ++failures;
        }
    }

    return failures != 0;
}
```

We need tests of the most-significant bit, and setting as well as resetting bits.  I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: If the order of bit fields is dependant on system endianness, can I use a preprossecor directive to determine what order the struct's members are declared in?

Comment: It's not dependent on _endianness_; that's only tangentially related.  I don't believe there's a reliable compile-time test - see this [relevant Stack Overflow answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/19376742/4850040).

Comment: I thought that [the bit field ordering was dependent on the endianness of the platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1490142/14797264), and it was limited to high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order

Comment: The 4 in `%#04hhx` in interesting.  I'd expect 2.

Comment: @QuestionLimitGoBrrrrr The bit field ordering is not specified to match the byte endianness.

Comment: @chux, the `4` is to give space for two hex digits after the two leading characters produced by the `#`.  Remember that the number is a _field width_, not a digit count (and yes, I do find it annoying to adjust them whenever I add or remove `#` from the conversion).

Comment: I don't think that bit-fields are even required to be sequential - as I understand it, a compiler is permitted to arrange bit fields for best performance (not straddling word/byte boundaries for instance).

Comment: 4 then does make sense in `%#04hhx`.  I find `0x%02X` to deemphasize the prefix as lower case, but upper case digits clearer to read output and ditch the pesky `#` with its 0 exemption.  I expect `%#04hhx\n", 0` to print `0000`.

Comment: Ah, `.2` is much nicer - I'll be using that from now on.  Thanks @chux!  (and yes, we can quickly demonstrate in shell that `printf '%#04x\n' 0` produces `0000` - ugh!)

Answer (score 2):

**I wanted to be able to have individual bit access in C without using a ton of functions to do bit manipulation on a `uint8_t`**

All things with bit-fields invite implementation defined behaviors.  Even using `unsigned char` is implementation defined.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type.  C17dr § 6.7.2.1 5

---

**Tell me where I could improve upon it**

It really is not that hard to form portable set/get bit functions.

Only 2 functions are needed: `BitGet()` and `BitSet()`

Sample unchecked code below uses `unsigned` as `uint8_t` itself is *optional*.  Narrow `uint8_t` is not really needed to make generic `set/get` as much code will promote to `unsigned/int` anyway.

```
#define UNSIGNED_BIT_WIDTH (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned))

unsigned BitGet(unsigned x, unsigned index) {
  index %= UNSIGNED_BIT_WIDTH; // Likely just an 'and' operation
  return (x >> index) & 1;
}

void BitSet(unsigned x, unsigned index, bool value) {
  index %= UNSIGNED_BIT_WIDTH;
  if (value) {
    x |= 1u << index;
  } else {
    x &= ~(1u << index);
  }
}
```

Other alternatives include macros, `inline`, etc.

---

**without using a ton of functions**

I estimate the weight of the above function, using [0.2 GB/g](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-weight-of-one-bit-computers), at about 6 pico-grams.

Comment: 5.9847 pico-grams...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What's a few femto-grams between friends?